# Скрипт тормозит во время загрузки изображений

Tags: javascript

подскажите плиз, есть простой скрипт

```js
var t = Date.now();

setInterval(function(){
  console.log(Date.now() - t);
},500);
```

и на странице есть четыре больших изображения. Вес каждого > 10 мб.
Вывод в консоли

```
501
1002
1684
2001
2747
3018
3659 
4559 
5410 
5502 
6002 
6916 
7462
7503 
8001 
8503 
9002 
9501
10002
```

То есть пока браузер грузит мои изображения, скрипт выполняется не каждые пол секунды. Подскажите почему так и что сделать, чтобы выполнялся каждые пол секунды. Если уменьшить вес изображений в 10 раз, то эффект пропадает

Спасибо

UPD Решение - изменить размер фотографий, спасибо

Comment: вообще этот скрипт просто показать что тормозит. 
А сделать хочу плавное движение курсора с собственной карьтинкой. Во время фоновой загрузки больших изображений плавного движения не получается

    $(document).mousemove(function(e){
        mouseX = e.pageX;
        mouseY = e.pageY;

        $('#move').css('transform', 'translate3d('+mouseX+'px, '+mouseY+'px, 0px)');
    });

Comment: Ну да, это особенность однопоточной работы js. Ничего сделать нельзя, только уменьшать размер картинок.

Comment: Попробуйте (если это JPG) картинкам задать `progressive` и качество 60. И откуда 10Мб? Это TIFF или карта Нарнии?

Comment: Просто фотография в высоком разрешении. Тут еще вопрос, какой оптимальный размер выбрать у фотографии, чтобы и грузилось быстро, и качество было высокое

Comment: @ЮрийКот  можно разбить картинку на тайлы, таким образом страница будет отзывчивее

Comment: ну а как же  WebWorker'ы ?

Answer (score 0):

не проверял, но как вариант посмотреть в сторону WebWorker'ов

https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/DOM/Using_web_workers
https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API

первая ссылка из гугла

[загрузка и декодирование картинок с помощью WebWorker](https://gist.github.com/ahem/d19ee198565e20c6f5e1bcd8f87b3408)